# Why is this happening in case of getchar and purchar

Tags: c

If I input `abc` as the text stream, `getchar()` reads it and `putchar` prints it. I used `printf` statements to trace whats exactly happening. But I get a strange output after I print the characters of input text stream. It enters once more the `while` loop and execute those two `printf` statements i.e when `i` is `4`. Does this get my Enter key as an input. If "yes" I also tried using `fflush` but that creates yet another issue. No character gets printed after I `fflush` creating problems with `getchar`. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

What happens if I use `fflush(stdin)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
   c=getchar();
   fflush(stdin);
   while(c!= EOF)
   {
     putchar(c);
     c=getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
   }
}
```

I write `ABC` on console when using `fflush`. It just `getchar()` 'a' and prints it. It doesn't even get the remaining characters.

Below it is the main program that I was talking about before I used `fflush`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c,i=1;

    c=getchar();

    while(c!= EOF)  // while(c=getchar!=EOF) putchar(c);
    {
      printf("\n\nthis is upper %d time in loop i.e. before the putchar\n\n",i);
      putchar(c);
      printf("\n\nthis is down %d time in loop i.e. after the putchar\n\n",i);
      c=getchar();
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin?lq=1); anything can happen.

Comment: _I write ABC on console using fflush. It just getchar() 'a' and prints it. It doesn't even get the remaining characters._ Because left off the input buffer by `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks i got it but what about the fix to this program, isn't there any way to not read in the \n character and i that assures guarantee unlike fflush

Comment: even the my country's best university prof. use fflush. It's not my fault. That is the reason i prefer stackoverflow come here to learn from you guys and coz that guarantee success unlike fflush which doesn't guarantee anything

Comment: you can check `c=='\n'`. What would you like to do? E.g. Display by removing newline from the input.

Comment: yes i want to remove this '\n' so it doesn't enters while loop and execute the printf statements 4th time...if i give the input text stream of size 3

Comment: @StackOverflow32 why don't you break out of the loop when `c == '\n'`

Comment: "... and how to fix it?" How to fix *what*??? What is your *intended* behavior? Nowhere in your question you explain how you want your program to work. The 4 iterations are perfectly expected: yes, it reads "abc" characters and the <enter> key, as it should. So, what do you want to "fix" and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n'){
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
    if(c == '\n')
        break;//exit this while-loop
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: if i use c == '\n' instead of c!= '\n' than what happened it just terminates. In `abc`  when i press enter i.e. '\n' atleast it should print `abc` and than terminate but it just terminates after i type `abc` and press enter....WHY?

Comment: @StackOverflow32 Loop is terminated condition becomes false when `c=='\n'` is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is executed 4 times because pressing `enter` causes a newline to show up on input. So, when `i == 4`, you will have `c == '\n'`.

You shouldn't `fflush(stdin)`, that's undefined behavior. Don't do it.

And also, this won't work the way you want:

```
while(c=getchar!=EOF) putchar(c);
```

Comparison has higher precedence than assignment, which means that this block of code is the same as:

```
while (c = (getchar() != EOF)) putchar(c);
```

Which is wrong. You have to use parentheses to give the assignment a higher priority:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c);
```

Comment: yaa that was "while(c=getchar!=EOF) putchar(c);" just not the part of the code....i know that != has higher precedence than = so c will get 1 or 0....i don't put brackets around (c=getchar())

Comment: In all of this `c` should be `int c;` so that it can store EOF properly.

Comment: but what is the answer to the question how can i fix it and not get enter or \n character read by getchar()? @FilipeGonçalves

Comment: @StackOverflow32 Just put it in the loop condition: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') { ... }`